# context free grammar for the following language

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata

```
{a^i b^j c^k | i != j j=k}
```

I am able to write the productions where #a = #b or #a != #b. But here, there are two condiitions. I tried writing the following production but here, #c is not equal to #b.

```
 S-> YC
 Y-> aYb | bB | aA 
 A->aA|e
 B->bB|e
 C->cC|e
```

Help

Comment: Are you sure there exists a CFG for this language?

Comment: No I'm not sure. Can you prove by pumping lemma if it does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

It is not context-free.

**Short answer**: Consider `a^m b^m c^m` it is in this language. Now pump through `a^m` and `b^m` you will get something like `a^(m+i)b^(m+i)c^m` but it is not in this language.

**What I mean by pump through:** consider your `uvwxy = a^m b^m c^m` such that `v=a^k` and `x=b^k` and `w` is something like `a^l b^t` such that `2k+l+t<n`. Because we have `uvwxy` is in our language we must have `u v^i w x^i y` is in our language, but `u v^i w x^i y = a^(m+i)b^(m+i)c^m` which is not in our language.